Escape PowerShell command when run from cmd.exe
When I am run my PowerShell command in Windows Command Prompt, (cmd.exe), it displays an error:
C:\temp>powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch "^," } )" 

At line:1 char:63
+ (Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch , } )
+ Missing expression after unary operator ','.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

It works well from Powershell Prompt:
PS C:\temp> Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch "^," }

How should I run it?

Try replacing the nested double quotes with single quotes instead: %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch '^,' }", or escape them using backward slashes: %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch \"^,\" }". Please note that -ExecutionPolicy Bypass is completely unnecessary when running a -Command; it is only useful for running PowerShell scripts, -File.

@Compo, While -ExecutionPolicy Bypass isn't needed for the particular command at hand, it situationally still can be, even without explicit script-file calls; see my answer for details. In short, assuming the effective execution policy is too restrictive (and not controlled via GPOs, which would prevent overrides): You always need it  with -File and you may need it with -Command. It's simplest to habitually specify it.

I was talking generally @mklement0, (although that may not have been clear). That lack of clarity was intentional however, because I had no intention of suggesting there may be edge cases when this command is only reading the content of a file.

@Compo: I don't think they're edge cases, given the range of conditions spelled out in my answer. Therefore, I think your advice, which sounds categorical ( "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass is completely unnecessary when running a -Command"), is misleading (though, to be clear, I don't doubt that it was well-intentioned). Also, for the sake of argument, if the premise of there only being edge cases were true, it's best to acknowledge them at least in the abstract (for brevity), with qualifiers such as "typically" or "mostly".

The issue is rises from the fact that you are using double quotes (") , Actually entire command is also enclosed in double quotes cmd.exe shell
So, these both double quotes are conflicting ,
To resolve this , you need to escape from the double quotes in power shell.
Now you can solve using single quotes( ' ) , Then the issue is resolved now
Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch '^,' } 

Alternatively ,You can use backslash (\) before using double quotes use  before every double quotes by forcefully mentioning I am using double quotes
Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch \"^,\" }



tl;dr

Either: Escape the embedded " chars. as \":

# Note the use of \"...\"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch \"^,\" } )" 


Or: Use single-quoting ('...') for the embedded string, assuming you don't need string interpolation (via "...", i.e an expandable string) on the PowerShell side ('...' is a verbatim string):

# Note the use of '...'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch '^,' } )" 

Two asides:

-NoLogo isn't needed, because it is implied by -Command

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass is a process-scoped override of the effective execution policy; it isn't strictly necessary with your particular command; however, you may need it even if you don't overtly call script files (*.ps1) (which is what  the execution policy is primarily about), because the execution policy can also block commands from (possibly auto-loading) modules, notably those implemented as script modules (written in PowerShell) and/or those that come with format- or type-definition files.



Background information:
The problem you're facing is rooted in the behavior of the PowerShell CLI (powershell.exe for Windows PowerShell, pwsh for PowerShell (Core) 7)
and therefore applies to all calls to the PowerShell CLI from the outside, not just from cmd.exe.

When you use the -Command (-c) CLI parameter (which is the default for powershell.exe, whereas it is -File (-f) for pwsh) to pass a piece of PowerShell code to execute, unescaped " characters are removed during the CLI's initial command-line parsing before the resulting argument(s) are evaluated as PowerShell code (see this answer for details).

E.g., powershell -c "hi!" breaks, because after stripping the unescaped ", PowerShell evaluates hi!, which it interprets as a command, which obviously doesn't exist.
Additionally, on a fundamental note: In your CLI call you're trying to pass your PowerShell code inside a single "..." string that has embedded " chars. ("(Get-Content .\FilteredANReport_5.csv | Where { $_ -notmatch "^," } )"), which intrinsically requires escaping them - see next point.


In order to pass " chars. so that they are retained as part of the PowerShell code to execute via -Command, escape them as \" - this applies whether or not they're part of an enclosing (unescaped) "..." string.

\" works robustly from PowerShell's perspective, in both editions, and also works when calling from Unix shells.

On Windows:

\" works robustly in no-shell invocations, such as from Task Scheduler, the Windows Run dialog (WinKey+R) or in commands launched via definitions in the registry.

Caveat: When calling from cmd.exe, using \" can situationally run afoul of cmd.exe's own parsing, because it doesn't recognize \" as an escaped "; the workaround is to (a) enclose the entire -Command argument in "..." and (b) use \"" for embedded " with powershell.exe / "" with pwsh.exe - see this answer for details.






